# Azure connect fails to connect to a worker role

Tags: azure, azure-connect

I have set up:

- a worker role that starts a native application running in the cloud, that listens on an internal endpoint on port 9900.
- an Azure connect according to Microsoft's instructions.

I can:

- ping the worker role instance using the IPV6 address obtained from the management portal.
- connect to it from a WebRole

However, I cannot connect to it from my local machine using the Azure connect. Every time I try, the connection attempt times out.

Should it be possible to connect to an internal endpoint using connect?

All the examples I have seen connect from a role in the cloud back to a local machine, not the other way round, but I cannot find anything that says that this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The above information is not enough to tell what is wrong or why you can not connect to your worker role from a local on-premise machine. Once Azure connect is installed and configured n both Azure Role and Local Machine, you can connect from both sides. Even when Azure connect do not have any updates in last 2 years, you still can use this preview/beta feature.

What you can do is run some troubleshooting test as described below and then provide some troubleshoting logs back here to provide accurate help.

- [Troubleshooting Windows Azure Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433016.aspx)

Also if possible re-check your Azure connect configuration using this info: [Checklist for Configuring Connections for Windows Azure Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433045.aspx)

Once side node, if you can use Windows Azure Virtual Networks, that is best rather then using Azure Connect.  Here is the link which can help:

- [Connecting Web or Worker Roles to a Simple Virtual Network in Windows Azure](http://michaelwasham.com/2012/08/06/connecting-web-or-worker-roles-to-a-simple-virtual-network-in-windows-azure/)

Comment: I ran the Azure connect diagnostics and eveything appears to be working. The fact that I can ping the machine suggests that it is working up to a point, but it seems to be being blocked somewhere between ariving at the machine and connecting to my application.

I did investigate Windows Azure Virtual Networks but it appears that it requires a router that supports a VPN in hardware, which mine does not. Azure connect on the otherhand uses a software based approach so is more suitable for my sittuation.

Answer (score 0):

The worker role endpoint has to be created as input not internal, even though it is not meant to be publicly accessible.

The Azure connect VPN then blocks all input apart from the computers added to the relevant group.

I tested it from another computer not added to the group, and it was blocked, so the VPN is working.